# Wierd image cut outs, making background bleed trough

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a website and now when I scroll, at very specific scrolling points you can see cut outs in the hero image making the background of the parallax effect visable. (In the snippet you can see them at the bottom of the hero image when you scroll down a bit) Simply what i'm asking for is why they are there and how can I remove them? I tried changing picture to ones with other sizes and sourceing them from diffrent places and nothing worked. I really can't put my finger on what is causing the wierd cuts.

[image: What is marked with red is the cutout im refering to]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Hamburger
  $(".burger-container").click(function () {
    $(".nav-menu").toggleClass("menu-opened");
    $("body").toggleClass("unscrollable");
  });

  // Dark-Light switcher
  $("body").toggleClass("light", localStorage.toggled == "light");

  document.getElementById("checkBox").addEventListener("click", darkLight);

  function darkLight() {
    if (localStorage.toggled != "light") {
      $("body").toggleClass("light", true);
      localStorage.toggled = "light";
    } else {
      $("body").toggleClass("light", false);
      localStorage.toggled = "";
    }
  }

  if ($("body").hasClass("light")) {
    $("#checkBox").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $("#checkBox").prop("checked", false);
  }

  //Info sections, lösenord
  $(function () {
    $(".info-sections").addClass("default");

    $(".info-sections").on("click", function () {
      var e = $(".expander > .info-sections");
      if (e.hasClass("expand")) {
        e.removeClass("expand");
        $(this).addClass("expand");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("expand");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Dark colors */
:root {
  --white-color: #d9d9d9;
  --black-color: #0d0d0d;

  --text-color: #d9d9d9;
  --hero-text: #d9d9d9;

  --grey-color-1: #595959;
  --grey-color-2: #666666;

  --body-bg-color: #262626;

  --text-hover-color: #a6a6a6;
}

/* Light colors */
:root .light {
  --white-color: #3d3c3c;
  --black-color: #e6e6e6;

  --text-color: #030302;
  --hero-text: #d9d9d9;

  --grey-color-1: #c4c4c4;
  --grey-color-2: #b1b1b1;

  --body-bg-color: #f5f5f4;

  --text-hover-color: #797274;
}

/* ======== MAIN CSS ======== */

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--body-bg-color) !important;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

main {
  background-color: var(--body-bg-color);
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
}

.top {
  z-index: 999;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3.5rem;
  background-color: var(--black-color);
}

.unscrollable {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* ======= PARALLAX ======= */

.parallax {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
}

.background {
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.foreground {
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(1.5);
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.background,
.foreground {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--hero-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 14rem;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero-text > h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.hero-text > p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

/* ======== HAMBURGER ======== */

.burger-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 0.1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

#burger {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  width: 18px;
  height: 8px;
  display: block;
  margin: -4px auto 0;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  background: var(--white-color);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.topBar {
  transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
}

.btmBar {
  transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  background: var(--black-color);
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-item {
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 1);
}

.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: 2.35;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--body-bg-color);
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  color: var(--text-hover-color);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu {
  height: 3.5rem;
  transition: height 0.4s;
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened {
  transition: height 0.4s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar {
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item {
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
}

/* ======== Dark Light switcher ====== */

.switcher > span {
  color: var(--text-color);
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.switcher {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggler-container {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 1);
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened ul.menu li.toggler-container {
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3.2rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #808080;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  content: "";
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #808080;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1.7rem);
  -ms-transform: translateX(1.7rem);
  transform: translateX(1.7rem);
}

/* ======== CONTENT ======= */

.text {
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.text2 {
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.content {
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.content h2 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

.info-sections {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.info-sections h3 {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.info-sections span {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-button {
  background: var(--grey-color-1) !important;
  color: var(--text-color) !important;
}

.accordion-item {
  background: var(--grey-color-2) !important;
  color: var(--text-color) !important;
  border-top: none !important;
  border-right: none !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white !important;
  border-left: none !important;
}

.accordion-button::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23ffffff'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/></svg>") !important;
}

/* ======== FOOTER ======== */

footer {
  padding: 4rem 0 6rem 0;
  background-color: var(--grey-color-1);
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

footer ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

footer ul a {
  color: var(--text-color);
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer ul li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
}

footer ul a:hover {
  color: var(--text-hover-color);
}

footer hr {
  color: var(--text-hover-color);
  max-width: 13rem;
  margin: 1.5rem auto;
}

footer .copyright {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: var(--text-hover-color);
}

/* ======== MEDIA QUERIES ======== */

/* TABLET */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* ======= FOOTER ======= */
  footer ul {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }

  footer ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0.2rem;
  }

  footer hr {
    max-width: 35rem;
  }
}

/* DESKTOP */
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  /* ======== MAIN CSS ======== */

  .top {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 35%;
    max-width: 20rem;
  }

  .hero-text > h1 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }

  .hero-text > p {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  /* ======= Scrollbar ======== */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    background: transparent;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: rgb(109, 109, 109);
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgb(148, 148, 148);
  }

  /* ======== HAMBURGER ======== */
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--black-color);
    backdrop-filter: none;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in, 0.5s ease-in;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .nav-menu.menu-opened {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .burger-container {
    display: none;
  }

  .menu-item {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 0.8rem;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .menu {
    flex-direction: row;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 1.5rem;
    height: 3.5rem;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .menu-item a {
    display: inline;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.12, 0.54, 0.94);
  }

  .flex-filler {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

  /* ======== Dark-light switcher ======== */

  .toggler-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 2.5rem 0 0;
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
  }

  .switcher > span {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 0 0.4rem;
  }

  .switch {
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 1.3rem;
  }

  .slider:before {
    height: 0.8rem;
    width: 0.8rem;

    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
  }

  input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1.2rem);
    -ms-transform: translateX(1.2rem);
    transform: translateX(1.2rem);
  }

  /* ======== CONTENT ========*/

  .content h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .content p {
    font-size: 1.15rem;
  }

  .expander {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50vh;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 50ms;
  }

  .expander .info-sections {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: var(--grey-color-1);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 50ms;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
  }

  .expander .default {
    height: 29rem;
    width: 50vw;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .expander .expand {
    height: 29rem;
    width: 100vw;
    background: var(--grey-color-2);
    color: var(--text-color-1);
    padding: 1rem;
  }

  .info-sections h3 {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .info-sections span {
    color: var(--text-color);
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }

  .info-top {
    margin: 1rem auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    max-width: 11rem;
  }

  .info-sections p {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .info-sections.expand span {
    display: none;
  }

  .info-sections.expand h3 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

/* MEDIUM-DESKTOP */
@media only screen and (min-width: 991px) {
  .expander .default {
    height: 26rem;
  }

  .expander .expand {
    height: 26rem;
  }

  .info-sections h3 {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }

  .info-sections span {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
  }

  .info-top {
    margin: 1rem;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .info-sections p {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }

  .info-sections.expand h3 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
}

/* XL-DESKTOP */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* ======= HAMBURGER ======= */

  .menu-item {
    margin-right: 1.3rem;
  }

  .menu-item a {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }

  /* ======= CONTENT ======= */

  .info-sections h3 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }

  .info-sections span {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
  }

  .expander .default {
    height: 23rem;
  }

  .expander .expand {
    height: 23rem;
  }

  /* ======= FOOTER ======= */
  footer ul {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  footer ul li {
    padding: 0 0.4rem;
  }

  footer hr {
    max-width: 40rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Lagar och säkerhet | Hem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;0,1000;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900;1,1000&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0"
    />
    <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top">
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-menu">
          <div class="burger-container">
            <div id="burger">
              <div class="bar topBar"></div>
              <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Hem</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="html/losenord.html">Lösenord</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="html/keylogger.html">Keylogger</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="html/statlig-kontroll.html">Statlig kontroll</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="html/tredjepartskod.html">Tredjepartskod</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="html/webbhotell.html">Webbhotell</a>
            </li>
            <li class="flex-filler"></li>
            <li class="toggler-container">
              <div class="switcher">
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> dark_mode </span>
                <label class="switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" />
                  <span class="slider"></span>
                </label>
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> light_mode </span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
      <header class="parallax">
        <img src="https://sosafe-awareness.com/sosafe-files/uploads/2023/02/Cybercrime-Trends-header-bg-scaled.jpg" class="background" alt="background" />
        <img src="https://sosafe-awareness.com/sosafe-files/uploads/2023/02/Cybercrime-Trends-header-img.png" class="foreground" alt="foreground" />
        <div class="hero-text">
          <h1>Lagar och säkerhet</h1>
          <p>
            Vilka lagar och regler finns det på internet och vad innebär de för användare och
            utvecklare?
          </p>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main>
        <div class="content container text-center py-5">
          <section class="row">
            <h2>Lagar på internet</h2>
            <p>
              Internetlagar skyddar användare på internet främst från dåliga aktörer. Ett viktigt
              exempel är den allmänna dataskyddsförordningen (GDPR), som påverkar hanteringen av
              personlig information från en utvecklares perspektiv. GDPR gäller för alla företag och
              organisationer inom EU och reglerar insamling, lagring och hantering av
              personuppgifter. Det ställer krav på samtycke och säkerhet för att skydda användarnas
              integritet.
            </p>
            <p>
              Utvecklare bör vara medvetna om sina skyldigheter enligt GDPR och implementera
              lämpliga tekniska åtgärder för att säkerställa att personuppgifter hanteras på ett
              säkert sätt. Detta kan inkludera kryptering av data, begränsad åtkomst till
              personuppgifter, rutiner för hantering av dataintrång och dokumentation av
              dataskyddsåtgärder.
            </p>
          </section>
          <section class="row align-items-center">
            <picture class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-3">
              <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="imgs/lagar-bild1200.jpg" />
              <source media="(min-width: 769px)" srcset="imgs/lagar-bild1000.jpg" />
              <img src="imgs/lagar-bild500jpg.jpg" alt="lagar" class="img-fluid lg-float-start" />
            </picture>
            <p class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
              Det är också viktigt att vara medveten om att många webbtjänster som används i Sverige
              ägs och administreras av amerikanska bolag, som lyder under amerikansk lag. Detta kan
              innebära att personuppgifter som överförs till eller lagras av dessa tjänster kan vara
              öppna för amerikanska myndigheter. Dessutom kan webbtjänsternas servrar vara placerade
              i tredjeländer, vilket ytterligare komplicerar rättsliga åtgärder och att kunna
              säkerställa att datan skyddas på rätt sätt.
            </p>
          </section>
          <section class="row">
            <p>
              För att skydda användares personuppgifter bör utvecklare använda tjänster och
              teknologier som uppfyller europeiska dataskyddsstandarder, som till exempel EU-US
              Privacy Shield Framework eller Standard Contractual Clauses (SCC). Genom att använda
              dessa tjänster kan utvecklare vara säkra på att de håller sig till de dataskyddslagar
              som GDPR kommer med.
            </p>
          </section>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="active">Hem</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/losenord.html">Lösenord</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/keylogger.html">Keylogger</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/statlig-kontroll.html">Statlig kontroll</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/tredjepartskod.html">Tredjepartskod</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/webbhotell.html">Webbhotell</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; All rights reserved by Vincent Cornelius</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a [**Minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ATP I would if I knew kind of where the problem lies. Right now I actually have no clue about what is causing the problem therefor I am refering to the snippet which is the only way I could make a reproduction at all.

Comment: I'm not too sure what I'm looking for in 'weird image cutouts'. Could you put a screenshot into your question?

Comment: Added the picture, that grey cutout in the red box is what i'm refering to @AHaworth

Comment: I am not seeing this on either Edge or FIrefox (WIndows 10). What OS and browser are you on? And what viewport size?

Comment: I am on chrome windows 10, and I see it on every viewport. Wierd that you can't see it at all, could it be something just for chrome? @AHaworth